# How can I emulate old photo cracks and creases procedurally?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, compositing-nodes, procedural, shader-nodes

This is the reference photo I've been using, and after a few attempts at it myself I wasn't able to get anything I was happy with.

[image]

Essentially I want to be able to add an image into the Shader node network (or Compositor), change the seed, and have a result similar to the reference.

<sub>I'm sure there is an answered question or a tutorial for this kind of thing, but I've looked around quite a bit and couldn't find anything.</sub>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is several types of cracks and scratches in your reference image ... some are easier to handle than others.

The simplest ones "empty maps" ... the key here is probably **Musgrave** texture node with low *Dimension* value ...

[image]

Secondly cracks that can be handled by **Voronoi** texture ... here it comes very sensitive in therm of value setup to get wanted result ... so something like this ...

[image]
Value node is used in "Seed" meaner.

Small painting cracks, seen at hairs (right bottom side), are the most difficult for me, but some similarity can be achieved by Voronoi > Minkowski ...

[image]
The trick to generate lines I could use Mapping node with some translation, but keep the nodetree light I used slightly different *Randomness* to let Compare node do its job.

*Voronoi* > **Minkowski** seems to be useful for other kind of damages - liquid or mold things (usually tinted to to brown paper) ...

[image]

With a small change of Scale value (here from 1 to 2) became like a paper damage, that can be used for Transparency and Normal factor ...

[image]

... final combination of those structures depends up to you :)

Before
[image]

After
[image]

To give final result a bit of thickness for cracks and creases you can combine all types to be reused into Height map

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is an exceedingly useful and comprehensive answer, thank you for sharing it with the community.

Comment: Really impressive :)) bookmarked

Comment: @JachymMichal ... also "really" value fragile :)